# Typography.Variants does not work on Segoe UI?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have this XAML code:

```
<RichTextBlock>
        <Paragraph>
            hello
            <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">
                hello
            </Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBlock>
```

Expected behavior: hello<sup>hello</sup>

What actually happens: hello hello

It works with some other fonts, such as Calibri.

Edit: Tested 7 months later, on latest Insider Release (14951) and still no fix. And feedback hub is broken on this release so I can't even report it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="16" Text="hello"/>
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="9" Text="hello"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

if you want to use RichTextBlock is also works

```
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RichTextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="16">
                <Paragraph>
                    hello
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>
            <RichTextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="9">
                <Paragraph>
                    hello
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
```